# Problems with generic Arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift2

Since I'm pretty new to native programming in iOS, I need some help with the following situation. What I need is a class which holds an array or dictionary with a combination of 2 integers as the key (used for coordiates in a grid matrix) and an Integer as the value. I found a solution in a tutorial somewhere, which looks like this:

```
class Array2D<T> {
    let columns: Int
    let rows: Int

    var array: Array<T?>

    init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows

        array = Array<T?>(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    subscript(column: Int, row: Int) ->T! {
        get {
            return array[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this type of array already has the length of rows*columns, as soon as the class is initialized, which I don't want. The array should be empty in the beginning. But if I initialize an empty Array, I get problems when it comes to getting or setting the value for a key which doesn't exist yet. Also, I need to be able to easily increment the values of a specific key (like `array[2, 3]++`). Does anybody have a good solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you clarify better what you want to achieve? Do you have a fixed number of rows/columns? What do you mean by "empty in the beginning"? What should `array[2, 3]` return if that value has never been set before?

Comment: Sorry @Martin R for not making it clear enough... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use it with optionals so there are no initial values set. In this example you have your `columns` an your `rows` which are optionals and initialized with `nil`. The array is initialized as an empty array.

```
class Array2D<T> {
    let columns: Int? = nil
    let rows: Int? = nil

    var array: Array<T?> = []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem with the subscript getter and setter, which throws an error when it tries to get or set a value for a key which doesn't exist (ie. `testArray[3, 4] = 6 // error`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not create `struct` for a coordinate like

```
struct Coordinate {
    let column: Int
    let row: Int
}
```

... then provide necessary implementations for `Equatable` and `Hashable` protocols, and then use it as a key in dictionary like:

```
struct Array2D<T> {
    private var storage = [Coordinate: T]()
    // ...
}
```

... and then provide `subscript` for that Array2D, which when a value is assigned would simply insert new entry into an underwater dictionary, and when the value is read, just read it from there.